# Assign classes to Custom fields

Tags: customization, tags

I have a post with 4 custom fields, and I am using [`the_meta( )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_meta) to display these.
I want to add an image to the list items, but a different image for each item
eg. key "Client" will have a small image of a person, key "Date" will have an image of a calendar...

The only way I can think of doing this is to somehow give each key a class and then use CSS to add a background image to the list-item.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to output these Custom Fields manually to do it.

You can do it like so (let's assume your custom fields are: `first-meta-key`, `second-meta-key`, `third-meta-key` and you set them single value - no field has multiple values assigned to it):

```
<ul>
  <li><span class="first-post-meta-key">Name: </span> <?php echo esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'first-meta-key', true)); ?></li>
  <li><span class="second-post-meta-key">Name: </span> <?php echo esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'second-meta-key', true)); ?></li>
  <li><span class="third-post-meta-key">Name: </span> <?php echo esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'third-meta-key', true)); ?></li>
</ul>
```

Another way would be:

```
<?php $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post->ID); ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach ( $custom_fields as $key=>$values ): ?>
    <?php foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value ): ?>
        <li><span class="<?php echo esc_attr($key); ?><?php echo esc_html($key); ?></span><?php echo esc_html($value); ?></li>;
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

PS. It's not tested (and written directly in here) so can be a little bit buggy.

Comment: So to do it this way:
`<ul>
  <li><span class="first-post-meta-key">Name: </span> <?php echo esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'first-meta-key', true)); ?></li>
  <li><span class="second-post-meta-key">Name: </span> <?php echo esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'second-meta-key', true)); ?></li>
  <li><span class="third-post-meta-key">Name: </span> <?php echo esc_html(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'third-meta-key', true)); ?></li>
</ul>`
I would just type the meta-key in the span and will the echo esc_html() part get the value?

Comment: `get_post_meta($post->ID, '<META_KEY>', true)` gets value of custom field `<META_KEY>` from post `$post->ID`